# Cannot access h2 user defined function in select clause but working in where clause

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, testing, h2, jpql

I have created a separate testing project to test this functionality with simple User entity having id and name attributes.

**Schema.sql File**

```
Create Table user (
    id Int Not Null Primary Key Auto_Increment,
    name Varchar(50) Default Null
);

Create Alias TEST FOR 
"com.example.demospringbootproject.h2.CustomH2.customTestFunction";

Create Alias ANOTHERTEST FOR 
"com.example.demospringbootproject.h2.CustomH2.customAnotherTestFunction";
```

**CustomH2 Function class**

```
package com.example.demospringbootproject.h2;
import com.example.demospringbootproject.model.User;

public class CustomH2 {

    public static Integer customTestFunction(Integer id){
        return id;
    }

    public static User customAnotherTestFunction(User user){
        return user;
    }
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
@Query("Select u From User u where TEST(u.id) = 1")
User repoFunction1();

@Query("Select ANOTHERTEST(u) From User u where u.id = 1")
User repoFunction2();
```

The first repo function is working fine

The second repo function is generating this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public 
abstract com.example.demospringbootproject.model.User 
com.example.demospringbootproject.repository.UserRepository.repoFunction2()!
```

I have tried renaming schema.sql to import.sql but same result.

My spring boot version: 2.5.7.

Java version: 1.8

**H2 Dependency**

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: `Create Alias TESTNAME` vs `ANOTHERTEST(u)`…

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. I have updated it